# CPack WIX post-flight script and installing files outside the install tree

Tags: cmake, wix, cpack

I'm trying to use the CPack WIX generator to install a service application.

How can I accomplish following tasks?

1. Install a file in %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\foo\bar.conf and make it read-writeable for administrators.
2. Run an installed program after installation is complete. The program would be called with a specific command line switch to install itself as a Windows service. In other words, the installer needs to be able to execute a program with administrative rights.
3. Run an installed program before an update or uninstall, for the purpose of stopping and removing the Windows service.

I suspect it will need to be done with patch xml file, but don't know where to start.

EDIT: Found a solution for tasks 2 & 3, by inserting ServiceInstall and ServiceControl fragments. No solution for task 1 though. Please help!

Comment: I know its old, but were you able to add ServiceInstall fragment using from within CMake?

Comment: @TCS unfortunately no. Gave up on it and used InnoSetup instead, which gave me a lot more freedom. I let CMake generate the InnoSetup script, using the `configure_file` function.